# What is the difference between an iterating iterable object returned by re.finditer() and typecasting it to list before iterating. PYTHON

Tags: python, list, iterator

I was solving a question python question on hackerrank. I came across a question where the following code passed:

```
import re
s = input()
ss = input()
o = list(re.finditer(r'(?=' + ss + ')', s))
if o:
    for i in o:
        print((i.start() , i.start() + len(ss) - 1))
else:
    print((-1, -1))
```

But the following one failed:

```
import re
s = input()
ss = input()
o = re.finditer(r'(?=' + ss + ')', s)
if o:
    for i in o:
        print((i.start() , i.start() + len(ss) - 1))
else:
    print((-1, -1))
```

You can see the difference on line number four. I am unable to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: Even using the (IMO) rather loose definition of type casting, this is *not* a type cast. `list(re.finditer(...))` builds an entirely new list by iterating over what amounts to a deferred function call. You aren't simply treating one value as if it had another type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list will evaluate to False if it is empty and to True if it is not.

Therefore this `if` is not entered if the `o` is an empty list:

```
if o:
```

An iterator does not *know* whether it is empty or not until it is consumed, so it is always *truthy*.

See for example:

```
list1 = []
list2 = [0]
iter1 = iter(list1)
iter2 = iter(list2)
>>> bool(list1)
False
>>> bool(list2)
True
>>> bool(iter1)
True
>>> bool(iter2)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
>>> if re.finditer("a", ""):
...     print("Y")
... 
Y
>>> if list(re.finditer("a", "")):
...     print("Y")
... 
>>>
```

From above you can see that in case of no matches, the generator object (iterator) still passes the condition (since it can't evaluate to False, in general, generators are just objects and therefore are always kind-of truthy as compared to containers that are `False` when empty) whereas an empty list, as expected, doesn't. The `boolean` value of generator objects are True:

```
>>> bool(range(1))
True
>>> bool(re.finditer("a", ""))
True
>>> bool(iter([1,2,3]))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

`finditer` returns an instance of `callable_iterator`, not a concrete container like a list. It has a boolean value of `True` whether or not the iterator can actually produce any values, because until you iterate over it, there's no way to tell if it will.

Answer (score 0):

Why it do not work was already explained by others I want to show possible solution without `list`-ing what `re.finditer` returned i.e.:

```
import re
s = input()
ss = input()
o = re.finditer(r'(?=' + ss + ')', s)
nothing = True
for i in o:
    nothing = False
    print((i.start() , i.start() + len(ss) - 1))
if nothing:
    print((-1, -1))
```

I simply set `nothing` to True and then inside `for`-loop I set it to `False`. Body of loop will be executed only if there is at least one element in `o`.